# Influence functions on neural networks: Help with understanding of result and derivation

Tags: deep-learning, statistics, mathematics, research

I'm working through a paper titled "[Understanding Black-box Predictions via Influence Functions](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/koh17a)" where they introduce the notion of influence functions from robust statistics to approximate the change in parameters when removing a training example.

They start off by establishing that the parameters that minimize the loss is given by
$$
\hat \theta = \arg \min_{\theta \in \Theta} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n L(z_i, \theta)
$$

Now they state that we would like to know what happens to the parameters when we remove a single training example $z = (x, y)$, which would be $\hat{\theta}_{-z} - \hat\theta$ where $\hat{\theta}_{-z}$ is the parameters obtained from training on every example except $z$.

$$
    \hat \theta_{-z} = \arg \min_{\theta \in \Theta} \sum_{z_i \neq z} L(z_i, \theta)
$$

What they introduce now is that the notion of influence functions can be used to upweight the training example $z$ by some small $\epsilon$ which approximates the effect of removing it which results in new parameters
$$
\hat{\theta}_{\epsilon, z} = \arg \min_{\theta \in \Theta} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n L(z_i, \theta) + \epsilon L(z, \theta)
$$

Here's where I'm unsure of what happens exactly. They write:

> *A classic result (Cook & Weisberg, 1982) tells us that the influence of upweighting $z$ on the parameters $\hat{\theta}$ is given by $\frac{d\hat\theta_{\epsilon, z}}{d\epsilon} \bigg|_{\epsilon=0} = - \mathbf{H}_{\hat \theta}^{-1} \nabla_{\theta} L(z, \hat \theta)$*

What is this classic result? I have been trying to go through their [reference](https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar?q=cache:-ANkB7mkHbAJ:scholar.google.com/%20cook%20and%20weisberg%201982&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) but can't seem to find anything that I can relate to the paper.
My question is then ***where this classic result is stated and how it is arrived at***? Additionally, what are the steps that are taken to arrive at $- \mathbf{H}_{\hat \theta}^{-1} \nabla_{\theta} L(z, \hat \theta)$ in their expression?

Thanks in advance!